# How to change font-size of Java doc inside Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.4 (Ultimate Edition) in Windows 10 x64, JDK 19. How to change font-size of Java doc inside Intellij IDEA?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click and use the context menu "Adjust Font Size..."

[image]